# Join several tables to one and then perform third join with different databases in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables which I would like to join in total. I would first like to join two tables, and then join this table to a third. These tables all belong to different databases. Here are my datasets:

```
database1
table1
Name       Id          Type        Date
bill       A           staff       1/1/2021
sally      B           staff       1/1/2021
jill       C           external    1/1/2021



database2
table2
Location      status   List
NY            1        A
CA            2        C
WA            3        D

database3
table3
Enroll     Plan       stat
N          B          1
Y          A          2
Y          A          3
```

**Desired**

```
Name      Id    Type         Location   status  List  Enroll   Plan  stat
bill      A     staff        NY         Y       A     N        B     Y
jill      C     external     CA         Y       C     Y        Y     Y
```

**Doing**

```
   SELECT
   [database1].[dbo].table1.Name,[database2].[dbo].table1.Id, [database1].[dbo].table1.Type,    
   [database2].[dbo].table2.Location,  [database2].[dbo].table2.status, [database2].[dbo].table2.List,    
   [database3].[dbo].table3.Enroll, [database3].[dbo].table3.Plan, [database3].[dbo].table3.stat
   FROM [database1].[dbo].table1
   INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].table2 ON
   [database1].[dbo].table1.ID = [database2].[dbo].table2.List 
   INNER JOIN NEWTABLE ON
   NEWTABLE.status = [database3].[dbo].table3.stat
   WHERE NEWTABLE.Date  = '2021/01/01'
   GROUP BY stat
```

*edited GROUP BY*

I am getting empty rows when I run this query.
I am still researching this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'd expect an error. You can't use `NEWTABLE` like that. Also, the GROUP BY is invalid.

Comment: ok I am still researching, I think I have to place the first statement in a parenthesis

Comment: Start with a single JOIN. When it works as expected, add a second JOIN. When also that works, add the third JOIN. When all the joining works, add the GROUP BY and set functions.

Comment: Tip: Table aliases make life easier. Do `FROM [database1].[dbo].table1 t1`, and you can do `t1.Name` etc in SELECT list, ON/WHERE etc.

Comment: ok I will try, thank you

Comment: How is the relationship defined to database/table 3? Surely you're not using `stat`?

Comment: yes, I have updated this to unique values

Comment: The query as you have it above doesn't work. Does it? You're missing an inner join to `table3` before you use it to join to `newtable`. It would be really helpful if you could setup a SQL Fiddle with your tables and data (ignoring the databases for the time being).

Comment: Ok I will remove the databases. Thank you